# Import the Spring source code In idea ,error about permission denied

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

when I imported the source of Spring code, beacause it is built with gradle, when I import it into idea, there is an error:

```
permission denied of F:\jdk1.8.0-25\jre\lib\security\cacerts(拒绝访问)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run IDEA as admin and import the project - if it works then the problem is in the folder permission - your user is not allowed to read from that folder and doesn't have access to the file. To give access follow this link: [answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed?auth=1)